# How to tally distinct combinations of rows in sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Say I have a collection of glass jars with some plastic balls of different colors in them.  There can be at most one ball of each color in every jar and every jar contains one or more balls.

I represent this collection with an sqlite table with the following columns:

JarID INTEGER, Color TEXT

A collection of three jars might then look like this:

```
JarID Color    
0,  'Red'    
1,  'Red'    
1,  'Green'    
2,  'Red'    
2,  'Blue'    
3,  'Red'
```

I'd like to write a query that will find all the different color combinations that exist in my jar collection, and list each combination alongside the total number of jars with that combination.
For the table above, the query should return either:

```
'Red', 2    
'Red,Green', 1    
'Red,Blue', 1
```

Or:

```
Red
2
Red
Green    
1    
Red    
Blue    
1
```

Currently I have a terrible mess of common table expressions and window functions that seems to achieve the desired result, but I can't help feeling that I'm missing some elegant, standard SQL solution to this.

Comment: I wonder how you would expect this to be at most n * log(n) when by design the possible combinations (in pairs only) of colors is n * n.

Comment: Good point, edited to factor number and of jars and colors separately.

Comment: Edited to focus on the query only, leaving out the complexity requirements.

Comment: By combinations do you mean up to 2 colors or more?

Comment: No, jars with a single color in them count too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Group_Concat function is what you're looking for, but first you need to aggregate and order your list so red-green-red comes out the same as green-red-red.

Do that with:

```
Select Jar_Id, Color
From Jars
Group By Jar_Id, Color
Order by Jar_Id, Color
```

Now feed that to a group_concat subquery to make a list of colors by jar_id:

```
Select Jar_Id, Group_Concat(Color) as Combos
From <first subquery>
Group By Jar_Id
```

Then feed that to an aggregator to count occurrences,  and you're done:

```
Select Combos, count(*) as Occurrences
From <second subquery>
Group By Combos
Order by Combos
```

Put it all together with:

```
Select Combos,count(*) as Occurrences
From (
    Select Jar_Id, Group_Concat(Color) as Combos
    From (
        Select Jar_Id, Color
        From Jars
        Group By Jar_Id, Color
        Order by Jar_Id, Color
    )
    Group By Jar_Id
)
Group By Combos
Order by Combos
```

One caution: Order Bys in a subquery are not strictly defined in SQL and might be ignored, but most implementations will do them.

Comment: Thanks,group_concat isn't quite standard but it works. It requires manually parsing the individual colors out of the result though so I'll still be looking for a way to get the 2nd form working.